# Using PHP to access JSON objects

Tags: php, json

I have a geo.json file that I'm trying to pull certain data out of using PHP. I want to start just by echoing the "properties" object within the "features" array.

My geo.json file (only part of it as this is repeated for every country):

```
    {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":
        [{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Bahamas","iso_a2":"BS","iso_a3":"BHS","iso_n3":"044"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-77.53466,23.75975],[-77.78,23.71],[-78.03405,24.28615],[-78.40848,24.57564],[-78.19087,25.2103],[-77.89,25.17],[-77.54,24.34],[-77.53466,23.75975]]],[[[-77.82,26.58],[-78.91,26.42],[-78.98,26.79],[-78.51,26.87],[-77.85,26.84],[-77.82,26.58]]],[[[-77,26.59],[-77.17255,25.87918],[-77.35641,26.00735],[-77.34,26.53],[-77.78802,26.92516],[-77.79,27.04],[-77,26.59]]]]}}
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php

$countryBordersJson = file_get_contents("countryBorders.geo.json");
$countryBordersJsonData = json_decode($countryBordersJson, true);

echo $countryBordersJsonData['features']['properties']['name'];

?>
```

I realise that the echo I've ended up with is probably totally wrong (I'm fairly new to PHP and JSON and this is part of my first solo project).

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: `features` is an array : `$countryBordersJsonData['features'][0]['properties']['name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there - once you use json_decode, it's an object not an array, so you need to use '->' to access its contents like so - https://3v4l.org/ZZNDg

```
$properties = json_decode($json)->features[0]->properties;
echo($properties->name);
```